# is using empty list expensive than doing a null check om a list in java?

Tags: java, optimization

I have below code. I am setting list to null at line 2 and further i am checking if list is null.I would like to know if creating an empty list is expensive than checking if list is null or not?

```
private void check(Product p){
 List<ProductAction> list=null; // line 2
 if(p.hasSubProducts){
     list = // list  of 
      ProductAction for sub products
 }
  if(list == null){
     //some logic 
  }
}
```

Comment: Same cost O(1), no difference

Comment: The cost is in the readability of the code. If you would do the same thing for a null list as you would with an empty list, why bother having to handle those cases separately?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just repeating the concept in the comments.

If you declare the `list` as `null` it is a declaration cost which is O(1) because you're just under the table declaring a pointer to `NULL` address, which is the base memory value.

Otherwise if you make a comparison `if(list == null)` you're just saying is the address value of `list` equal to `NULL` address. Obviously this operation costs O(1), therefore the cost is the same.

Probably in your situation the best way to code in order of readability is:

```
private void check(Product p){
 List<ProductAction> list; // this is already equal to null
 if(p.hasSubProducts()){
     list = // list  of 
      ProductAction for sub products
    // i assume you declare and update the list here
 }
  if(list == null){
     //some logic 
  }
}
```

This because of comments inside the code.